# Firebase Firestore sends FIRTimestamp instead of Timestamp

Tags: json, swift, firebase

When downloading a document from Firebase Firestore, it contains two Timestamp objects. In the Json file, it still uses the old class called FIRTimestamp instead of just Timestamp, which generates an error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid type in JSON write (FIRTimestamp)'
```

and `Thread 1: "Invalid type in JSON write (FIRTimestamp)"`.

The JSON looks like this:

```
["ZH 123456": {
ende = "<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1689022874 nanoseconds=129000000>";
flinkeyId = "12345678";
kennzeichen = "ZH 123456";
name = "Renault Clio";
start = "<FIRTimestamp: seconds=1682110874 nanoseconds=129000000>";
}, ... ]
```

I've already updated the Podfile so that all the dependencies are on the latest version. Even in the Firebase Firestore console, it displays that "ende" and "start" have a type of "timestamp".

The code to decode the JSON object is as following:

```
struct ReservationInformation: Codable {
    let flinkeyId: String
    let kennzeichen: String
    let name: String
    let start: Timestamp
    let ende: Timestamp
}
...
    print(reservations)
    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: reservations, options: [])
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: ReservationInformation].self, from: jsonData)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that `Timestamp` is not a supported type of the `Codable` protocol, since it is a `Firestore` custom type, not a native Swift type. I suggest using `Date`,  type and that is supported by `Codable`, and it's easily convertible between `Timestamp`.

Answer (score 0):

You are *probably* not receiving the old FIRTimestamp object: you are receiving a Timestamp object which debug description is "<FIRTimestamp...". You can convert the value to `Date` or `String`, but you can't decode `Timestamp`.

My personal solution for simplicity is to use a `String` type in the model, which can later be converted to `Date` by calling a dedicated computed variable. In such case, before decoding you can use the following code to turn the timestamps (in either of the types) to strings.

```
        reservations.filter {
            $0.value is Date || $0.value is Timestamp
        }.forEach {
            if $0.value is Date {
                let date = $0.value as? Date ?? Date()
                reservations[$0.key] = date.timestampString as? Value
            } else if $0.value is Timestamp {
                let date = $0.value as? Timestamp ?? Timestamp()
                reservations[$0.key] = date.dateValue().timestampString as? Value
            }
        }


    let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: reservations, options: [])
    let decoded = try JSONDecoder().decode([String: ReservationInformation].self, from: jsonData)
```

The `.timestampString` method is here below:

```
extension Date {

    var timestampString: String {
        Date.timestampFormatter.string(from: self)
    }
    
    static private var timestampFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        dateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(identifier: "UTC")
        return dateFormatter
    }
}
```